# Xcode 7 GM Show Segue Turns Into Modal Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue, xcode7

I have an app with a navigation view controller and once a cell is tapped on, a screen is pushed on top of it. However, when testing this app on a simulator and on multiple devices, the push segue somehow turns into a modal segue. These pictures will show a gist of what is happening:

Table View:

[image]

What is supposed to happen (Show segue):

[image]

What happens instead (Modal segue):

[image]

I am running this on an iOS simulator but for my app the result is the same. I have seen people post about this issue taking place on iOS 7, but is this supposed to happen with iOS 9?? Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like the "Master-Detail Application" template of Xcode, which uses `UISplitViewController` (**not** `UINavigationController`, like you mention...). Perhaps you are not allowed to post screenshots of your actual app, and used the template instead to convey the idea?

Comment: Does your segue still appear as "show" in Interface Builder? Did you try deleting the segue and recreating it?

Comment: @NicolasMiari that is what I am doing just to give an idea and I tried deleting and recreating multiple times. I even tried deleting the navigation controller in between but that did not change anything

Comment: ...and it was working until the last beta (before GM)?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I had submitted it to the App Store and it was working fine on every device I tested on and simulator. Then I update the app and find this error. That was on Xcode 6, on which it seems to be working fine but once updated it starts behaving like this. On Xcode 7, I can actually see the issue on the simulator (which I was unable to do before) but I have no indication of why this is happening.

Comment: Just to chek: When you select the segue in Interface Builder, does it appear as "Show (e.g. Push)" on the right side Inspector? Is the source view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: @NicolasMiari it appears as "show (eg Push)" and the source view controller is embedded in a navigation view controller. i once tried to set it as a "show detail" but that did not work

Comment: Then, I don't know what to say. I have a project that does a similar thing, and it is working (Xcode 7 GM)...

Comment: @NicolasMiari you have a project that does the same thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89636/discussion-between-nicolasmiari-and-kodinc).

Comment: This same change from show to modal just happened to me in XCode 8.2. Recreating segues helped fixing navigation bars but now I can see only Back button to go back but it used to show the view controller title instead. Grrhhhh

Comment: it turned out that Navigation Item somehow was added on all viewcontrollers that supperimposed the actual navigation bar, all I needed to do to get rid of that Back button and get my view controller titles back - delete this Navigation Item. No idea why this happened though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution. It appears, that now, in Xcode 7, you should make a segue not to navigation controller, but to your `viewController` directly, in order to achieve desired push segue.

Comment: is this just for xcode 7, and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: It is just for Xcode 7, because I had exactly your problem when I upgraded.  I didn't look for it in documentation, maybe. But it solves the problem for sure. Looks like a new way to manage navigationController and Segues.